# Created compose project not listed when using docker compose package in Go

Tags: go, docker-compose

I am trying to build a simple code (https://go.dev/play/p/9fcBrgupBpW) in Golang to interact with Docker Compose.

The problem is - after creating compose project based on the given `docker-compose.yml` file, no project actually is listed.

What's expected is something like

```bash
$ docker compose ls -a
NAME                STATUS              CONFIG FILES
wp                  created(2)          /home/ubuntu/junk/wp/docker-compose.yml
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

#### UPDATE 1

Inspected the containers created by my code, I noticed that `com.docker.compose.project` is missing:

```json
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "350500cdc96e61d71aaecffc207b3b5fd3acbd3e76f29fd278be28265052d7e6",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.depends_on": ""
            }
```

Any one knows why it is missing according to my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `projectOptions` is not public, so I will have to recreate the same logic in my code to get this to work:

[image]

So what ended up in my code is

```golang
func (s *service) create(ctx context.Context) {
    yamlFilePath := "/home/ubuntu/junk/wp/docker-compose.yml"

    options, err := cli.NewProjectOptions(
        []string{yamlFilePath},
        cli.WithResolvedPaths(true),
        cli.WithOsEnv,
        cli.WithDotEnv,
        cli.WithConfigFileEnv,
        cli.WithDefaultConfigPath,
    )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    project, err := cli.ProjectFromOptions(options)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for i, s := range project.Services {
        s.CustomLabels = map[string]string{
            api.ProjectLabel:     project.Name,
            api.ServiceLabel:     s.Name,
            api.VersionLabel:     api.ComposeVersion,
            api.WorkingDirLabel:  project.WorkingDir,
            api.ConfigFilesLabel: strings.Join(project.ComposeFiles, ","),
            api.OneoffLabel:      "False", // default, will be overridden by `run` command
        }
        if options.EnvFile != "" {
            s.CustomLabels[api.EnvironmentFileLabel] = options.EnvFile
        }
        project.Services[i] = s
    }

    if err := s.apiService.Create(ctx, project, api.CreateOptions{}); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Basically I copied the same code from https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/v2/cmd/compose/compose.go#L190-L203